# Using the digits 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7, with no repetition of digits, how many three digit odd numbers greater than 300 can you form?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We have three digits.

The first digit cannot be 1, because that would mean that the number would be lower than 300. That means that for the first digit, there are 5 possible cases.

The second digit can be any number in the set, and because one number has already been used, there are 5 possible cases for the second digit.

The third digit must be odd, and because there are both 4 numbers remaining in the set and 4 odd numbers in the set, there are 4 possible cases for the third digit.

(5 possible cases) * (5 possible cases) * (4 possible cases) == 100 possible cases.

Apparently this approach is completely wrong. Can someone please explain to me why my approach is wrong, provide the correct approach, and then explain why the correct approach is the correct approach?

Comment: You need to consider the parity of the two leading digits.  If they are, say, $4,6$ then you have $4$ odd digits to choose from for the units place.  But if they are $3,1$ then you only have two odd digits for the units place.

Comment: Might be easier to start from the units place, though of course you still have to separate the case where the units digit is $1$ from the other possibilitlies.

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting that the choice of the first and second digit might limit the choice for the third digit.

Let’s elaborate:

The first digits can be any of the five digits greater than $1$.
IF the first digit is $4$ or $6$, then we have $4$ possible odd digits left for the last digit. Then we have a total of four numbers for the second digits left.

This makes $2\cdot 4\cdot 4=32$ possible combinations.

Now, if the first digit is one of $3,5,7$ then we only have three odd digits left for the third, and again four digits for the middle one.

This makes $3\cdot 3\cdot 4 = 36$ possible combinations.

In total we have $32+36=68$ combinations.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to calculate all three digits number greater than $300$ and then subtract the even numbers from these.

The number of all three digits number greater than $300$ is $5\times 5\times 4=100$. The number of three digits number greater than $300$ that are even is $4\times 4\times 2=32$. Therefore the number of three digits odd number greater than $300$ is $100-32=68$. Here I use the fact that the even numbers are both greater than $3$ so regardless of the rightmost digit we only have $4$ choice for leftmost digit.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

The rightmost digit must either specifically be $(1)$, or it must specifically be in $\{3,5,7\}$.

$\underline{\text{Case 1: Rightmost digit is} ~(1)}$ 
Then the other two digits can be any $2$ from $\{3,4,5,6,7\},$ in any order.
The enumeration is $\binom{5}{2} \times 2! = 20.$

$\underline{\text{Case 2: Rightmost digit is in} ~\{3,5,7\}}$ 
Here, there is a shortcut.
If the leftmost digit was permitted to be $1$, then the enumeration would be $3$ times the enumeration in Case 1.

Therefore, the **starter** enumeration for Case 2 is $60$.
From this, it is necessary to deduct the number of ways of forming a number in Case 2, where the leftmost digit is $1$.

With the leftmost digit $= 1$, and $3$ choices for the rightmost digit, there are then $4$ choices for the middle digit.  Therefore, the number of ways that Case 2 can be satisfied with a $1$ in the leftmost digit is $3 \times 4 = 12$.

Therefore, the computation for Case 2 is $60 - 12 = 48.$

---

Final computation: $20 + 48 = 68$.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out $1$ for the moment, and choosing from units to hundreds, we get
$U\;\, T\; H$
$3\cdot 5\cdot 4 = 60$

But any  one of the $3 U's\quad XOR\quad 5T's$ can be replaced by $1$

thus ans = $60+3+5 = 68$